# Dynamically create and initialize an array of pointers to struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Here is an example code of what I'm trying to achieve

```
typedef struct
{
  int x_pos, y_pos;
} A;

typedef struct
{
  A **arrayAp;
} B;

int main(void) {
    B B;
    int n = 10;
    A *array[n];
    B.arrayAp = array;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    B.arrayAp[i] = malloc(sizeof(A));
    B.arrayAp[i]->x_pos = i;
    B.arrayAp[i]->y_pos = i + 1;
    }
    printf("%d",B.arrayAp[0]->x_pos);
}
```

It works as I want it to work. I can access elements of "array" using "arrayAp" pointer. But when I try to move some of this code to function for example:

```
A * makeAnArray()
{
    int n = 10;
    A *array[n];
    return &array;
}
```

and then assign value that it returns to "arrayAp"

```
B.arrayAp = makeAnArray();
```

Now I can't access first element of the array. Program just crash.

```
printf("%d",B.arrayAp[0]->x_pos);
```

But starting from second element everything works the same.

But the bigger problem I get when I try to move to function this code:

```
void initializeAnArray(B *B)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    B->arrayAp[i] = malloc(sizeof(A));
    B->arrayAp[i]->x_pos = i;
    B->arrayAp[i]->y_pos = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Seems like it has no effect. When i'm trying to access array member through "arrayAp" pointer i'm getting some "random" values from memory.

```
typedef struct
{
  int x_pos, y_pos;
} A;


typedef struct
{
  A **arrayAp;
} B;

A * makeAnArray()
{
    int n = 10;
    A *array[n];
    return &array;
}

void initializeAnArray(B *B)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    B->arrayAp[i] = malloc(sizeof(A));
    B->arrayAp[i]->x_pos = i;
    B->arrayAp[i]->y_pos = i + 1;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    B B;
    B.arrayAp = makeAnArray();
    initializeAnArray(&B);
    printf("%d",B.arrayAp[1]->x_pos);
}
```

Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function should be:

```
A * makeAnArray()
{
    int n = 10;
    //A *array[n]; --> This is local to this function so won't work
    A *array = malloc(sizeof(A)*n); //--> Dynamic allocation
    return array;
}
```

Comment: @ChLys - you could have passed `int n` as an argument.

Comment: I know, it just an example. I have a different program where n is calculated by a function. Just to make it simple I wrote this example.

Comment: Ah great - i will use this later for myself - simple and useful :)

Answer (score 2):

```
A * makeAnArray()
{
    int n = 10;
    A *array[n];
    return &array;
}
```

You are returning a local pointer which dies after the function ends and causes UB.

Moreover return type of your function should be `A**` and you should allocate memory with `*alloc` and return to ensure every instance is different and is alive after the function call.

**Possible fix**

```
A * makeAnArray()
{
    int n = 10;
    A *array = malloc(n * sizeof(A));
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The part

```
A * makeAnArray()
{
    int n = 10;
    A *array[n];
    return &array;
}
```

is not going to work. The array `array` might be allocated on the stack, it cannot be accessed via the return value after termination of `makeAnArray`; the result is undefined behaviour.

Comment: `C` specifications never mention that stack **must** be used. You should say, it is usually implementted as stack.